# How to get info about element in mobile app (android) through another app?

Tags: java, android

I need to create a mobile app for android, with which it will be possible to show a hint for a certain element of another application. To do this, I need to find out information about an element of another application and transfer it to my application in order to draw a tooltip later. How can I do that?

Comment: hello and welcome to stackoverflow, be more specific about what you're asking and please add some code to help with that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may it with Android Accessibility or UIAutomatorviewer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).